# attachment not sent

Tags: 8

I have 5 contact forms on site running drupal 8 with attachments enabled on each of them. The Emails are coming through fine but the attachments are not coming through. Please help. I have looked for solutions online but cant find any.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write custom mail plugin that will support attachments, Drupal cannot/won't handle that on its own.

For example this is my mailgun plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\foo\Plugin\Mail;

use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailFormatHelper;
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
use Mailgun\Messages\MessageBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginFormInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * @Mail(
 *   id = "mailgun",
 *   label = @Translation("Mailgun"),
 *   description = @Translation("Send e-mails via Mailgun service.")
 * )
 */
class MailGunMail implements MailInterface, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface, PluginFormInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The plugin instance id.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $plugin_id;

  /**
   * The config factory service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $config;

  /**
   * The logger factory service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $logger;

  /**
   * Constructs MailgunMail object.
   *
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin id.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
   *   The config factory service.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_factory
   *   The logger factory service.
   */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_factory) {
    $this->plugin_id = $plugin_id;
    $this->config = $config_factory;
    $this->logger = $logger_factory;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $container->get('config.factory'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function format(array $message) {
    // Explode the recipients into array.
    $message['to'] = array_map('trim', explode(',', $message['to']));

    // Join the body array into one string.
    $message['body'] = implode("\n", $message['body']);

    return $message;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function mail(array $message) {
    $config = $this->config->get('foo.email_plugin.' . $this->plugin_id);
    $mailgun_key = $config->get('key');
    $domain = $config->get('domain');

    if (empty($mailgun_key)) {
      $this->logger->get('foo')->error('Missing Mailgun key.');
      return FALSE;
    }

    if (empty($domain)) {
      $domain = $this->config->get('foo.site')->get('domain');
    }

    $site_name = $this->config->get('system.site')->get('name');
    $mailer = new Mailgun($mailgun_key);
    $email = new MessageBuilder();

    array_map([$email, 'addToRecipient'], $message['to']);
    $email->setSubject($message['subject']);
    $email->setFromAddress(sprintf('%s <%s>', $site_name, $message['from']));
    $email->setReplyToAddress(empty($message['reply-to']) ? $message['from'] : $message['reply-to']);
    // @see https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/259
    $email->setHtmlBody(str_replace("\n", '<br>', $message['body']));

    // Add support for file attachments.
    if (!empty($message['attachments'])) {
      /** @var \Drupal\File\Entity\File $attachment */
      foreach ($message['attachments'] AS $attachment) {
        $email->addAttachment($attachment->getFileUri(), $attachment->label());
      }
    }

    // Note: headers are ignored on purpose.
    // Having 'from' header would cause Mailgun to halt the message with "multiple from"
    // error. Having 'reply-to' would cause two identical headers and so on.
    // All headers added by the \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager::doMail
    // are handled by the Mailgun service so the only think we have to care about
    // is the message content.

    try {
      $mailer->sendMessage($domain, $email->getMessage(), $email->getFiles());
      return TRUE;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      watchdog_exception($this->plugin_id, $e);
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config->get('foo.email_plugin.' . $this->plugin_id);

    $form['key'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API key'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('key'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    ];

    $form['domain'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Domain'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('domain')
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config->getEditable('foo.email_plugin.' . $this->plugin_id);
    $config->set('key', $form_state->getValue('key'));
    $config->set('domain', $form_state->getValue('domain'));
    $config->save();
  }

}
```

And of course you have to properly provide the attachments via `hook_mail`.